# Datetime conversion in the wrong format (daylight?)

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I call a soap web service which return an xml with a birthdate in this format:

```
1948-03-13+02:00
```

I also have a helper class which converts my XML to an object so I can access it.

This normally works with no problem, but in this specific case when I test the value of the variable (a `DateTime` variable) it returns

```
12/03/1948 23.00.00
```

It seems like it removes 2 hours, so when I save the date the is a risk that I have the wrong date stored.

Could be a problem of daylight saving time? in Italy in that period there was a change of daylight

The helper class is an autogenereted code the problem is in this field:

```
Private dataRegolarizzazioneField As Date
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType:="date")>  _
    Public Property dataRegolarizzazione() As Date
        Get
            Return Me.dataRegolarizzazioneField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.dataRegolarizzazioneField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Can you please show a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: "I also have a helper class which converts my XML to an object so I can access it." - it sounds like the code in that class may be at fault, but we'll need to see the code. Also, what do you *want* the result to be, exactly? What do you want to do with the +02:00?

Comment: Sorry, now i edited the main post
@JonSkeet nothing, i just want the correct date

Comment: Okay, I suspect that using `DateTimeOffset` would help here. (You should be able to use an automatically implemented property, too, which would make your code a lot simpler.)

Comment: I think you mean Daylight Saving Time. The amount of daylight does not affect how computers calculate dates and times :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes sorry, in italy there is no such terms.. there is solar and legal hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This person's birthday was the daylight time changeover day in 1948.

Many applications of date/time datatypes benefit from diligent handling of time zones. That is *not true for dates of birth*.  Consider this: if your birthday is March 27 and you were born in Italy, and you travel to Australia, your birthday is March 27, in Australia, all day.  To compute your age, we compare your date of birth with the present date in local time.

So, you need to use local time. Strip off the timezone offset. If your input strings are consistently formatted, you can use this.

```
 const string pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
 datestring = datestring.Substring(0,10);
 DateTime birthdate;
 if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(datestring, 
                             pattern,
                             null,
                             DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                             out birthdate)) {
   /* handle date parse error */
 }
```

[Dotnet's date format strings are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

If you store this in a SQL database, use the `DATE` datatype for that column; it typically doesn't take the current timezone into account.

Comment: `const string pattern = 'YYYY-MM-dd'; `
There is the wrong date inside, how can it work?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. it should be `yyyy-MM-dd`. Please see my edit.

Comment: also, if i do object.Tostring() it gets me the date of yesterday, so it not work

Answer (score 0):

maybe, its the type not the daylight. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime

when i work with time and dates I use `DateTimeOffset` and I dont have problems like that. Change to `DateTimeOffset` to see if it works.